# Google API client ID isn't authorizing

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube, google-api, youtube-api

I am trying to make an app to do a basic search for youtube videos. I'm using the Youtube Data API and I went to the google developer's console and created a client ID for my domain name.

I downloaded the auth.js and the search.js that Google has on their sample code section and put my client ID into where it says 'my client id' but the application isn't working. I used console.log and it seems that I'm not getting past the function 'checkAuth'.

Am I missing something?? Here is a link to the page: http://www.vidme.cassandraburnscreative.com/#search

Here is the auth.js and search.js together

```
var OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID = 'my client ID';
var OAUTH2_SCOPES = [
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube'
];


googleApiClientReady = function() {
  console.log("googleApiClientReady");
  gapi.auth.init(function() {
    window.setTimeout(checkAuth, 1);
    console.log("gapi.auth.init");
  });
}


function checkAuth() {
  gapi.auth.authorize({
    client_id: OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID,
    scope: OAUTH2_SCOPES,
    immediate: true
  }, handleAuthResult);
  console.log("checkAuth");
}


function handleAuthResult(authResult) {
  if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
    // Authorization was successful. Hide authorization prompts and show
    // content that should be visible after authorization succeeds.
    $('.pre-auth').hide();
    $('.post-auth').show();
    loadAPIClientInterfaces();
    console.log("Load Interfaces");
  } else {

    $('#login-link').click(function() {
      console.log("nope");
      gapi.auth.authorize({
        client_id: OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID,
        scope: OAUTH2_SCOPES,
        immediate: false
        }, handleAuthResult);
      console.log("HandleAuthResult");
    });
  }
}

function loadAPIClientInterfaces() {
  gapi.client.load('youtube', 'v3', function() {
    handleAPILoaded();
    console.log("handleAPILoaded");
  });
}

function handleAPILoaded() {
  $('#search-button').attr('disabled', false);
}

function search() {
  var q = $('#query').val();
  var request = gapi.client.youtube.search.list({
    q: q,
    part: 'snippet'
  });

  request.execute(function(response) {
    var str = JSON.stringify(response.result);
    $('#search-container').html('<pre>' + str + '</pre>');
  });
}
```

and the html

```
<div class="wrapper">

<div id="buttons">
<p>Search For an Artist:</p>
      <label> <input id="query" placeholder='+ Add Artist' type="text"/>
      <button id="search-button" disabled onclick="search()">Search</button>
      </label>
</div>
    <div id="search-container">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to be connected or use Oauth2 to search something with the YouTube API.
You only need an [api key](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/register).

A sample example :

```
function googleApiClientReady() {
    var apiKey = 'YOUR_API_KEY';

    gapi.client.setApiKey(apiKey);
    gapi.client.load('youtube', 'v3', function() {
        isLoad = true;
    }); 

    request = gapi.client.youtube.search.list({
        q: q,
        part: 'snippet'
     });
    request.execute(function(response) {
        //your code to here
    });
}
```

Don't forget to add this file to your index.html and add this following line after :

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=googleApiClientReady"></script>
```

From doc [YouTube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/javascript?hl=fr)

Comment: Thank you so much this is exactly what I needed. I couldn't find a way to use the API key anywhere so I was trying to use the client ID.